# sed command to substituite a value only in second line of occurrence

Tags: linux, sed, substitution

sed command

How to substitute only on the second line of occurrence using sed command in Linux?

I am trying the below command:

```
sed -i -e 's/GET:CNTR,01010005/GET:CNTR,01010006/2' -e 's/GET:CNTR,01010006/GET:CNTR,01010008/' /data0101/ee_stats.out
```

This seems not to change the 2nd line of occurrence.

I need to change from:

```
GET:CNTR,01010005,eir,0,255;
GET:CNTR,01010005,eir,0,255;
GET:CNTR,01010006,eir,0,255;
```

to:

```
GET:CNTR,01010005,eir,0,255;
GET:CNTR,01010006,eir,0,255;
GET:CNTR,01010008,eir,0,255;
```

Comment: "The second line of occurence"? In your example you change *two* lines.

Comment: [root@bteir data0101]# cat ht
hello
hello
hallo
[root@bteir data0101]# sed -i -e 's/hallo/hey/' -e 's/hello/hallo/2' /data0101/ht
[root@bteir data0101]# cat ht
hello
hello
hey
[root@bteir data0101]#

Here I want to change the second line "hello" to "hallo" as well

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case, `ed` is a better choice than `sed` for modifying files, as that's what it was designed for in the first place:

```sh
printf '%s\n' '/01010005/;/01010005/;.s/01010005/01010006/' w | ed -s /data0101/ee_stats.out
```

This (rather ugly, granted) set of commands will find the second line containing `01010005` (Adjust RE as needed; I didn't want to use the full line to keep it simple) and replace it with `01010006`, and then **w**rite the changed file back to disk.

The first `/01010005/` finds the first line with that pattern, and the semi colon sets the current line cursor to it. The second one finds the first matching line *after* the current line (Thus the second match in all), and sets that to the current line. `.` in an address range means the current line, so only that one line is modified (Leaving out the `;.` would use lines in the range starting at the first match and ending at the second match, changing both matching lines; if more than one address before a `s///`, the last two are treated as a range of lines).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/\(5,.*\n.*\)5,/\16,/;s/\(6,.*\n.*\)6,/\18,/;P;D' file
```

Append the following line.

If the first line value is duplicated in the second, amend the second.

Print then delete the first line and repeat.

N.B. The `D` deletes the first line in the pattern space and if the pattern space is not empty, defers the implicit replenishing of the pattern space by the sed cycle i.e. the sed cycle uses what was left over in the pattern space until it has all gone.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by using the following method.

```
sed -i -e "/GET:CNTR,01010005/ {n; :a; /GET:CNTR,01010005/! {N; ba;}; s/GET:CNTR,01010005/GET:CNTR,01010006/; :b; n; $! bb}" /data0101/ee_stats.out
sleep 5
sed -i -e "/GET:CNTR,01010006/ {n; :a; /GET:CNTR,01010006/! {N; ba;}; s/GET:CNTR,01010006/GET:CNTR,01010008/; :b; n; $! bb}" /data0101/ee_stats.out
```